# Make unique a recurrent string in a file in linux

Tags: sed

I have a file prueba.ldif like this:

```
dn: EpsStaInfId=EpsStaInf,serv=EPS,mscId=0015f5e3d05d4d52b0cb85db69474db3,ou=multiSCs,dc=three
structuralObjectClass: EpsStaticInf
objectClass: EpsStaticInf
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20220303153032Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220303153032Z
EpsStaInfId: EpsStaInf
EpsProfileId: 10
EpsOdb: 0
EpsRoamAllow: TRUE
CDC: 1
EpsIndDefContextId: 1
EpsIndAmbrMaxUl: 320000000
EpsIndAmbrMaxDl: 1024000000
EpsRoamRestrict: TRUE
EpsTenantId: 1
EpsIndContextId: 1
EpsIndContextId: 2

dn: EpsStaInfId=EpsStaInf,serv=EPS,mscId=0040fb1140104f9fbc4be38be3db5965,ou=multiSCs,dc=three
structuralObjectClass: EpsStaticInf
objectClass: EpsStaticInf
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20220301120221Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220301120221Z
EpsStaInfId: EpsStaInf
EpsProfileId: 10
EpsOdb: 0
EpsRoamAllow: TRUE
CDC: 1
EpsIndDefContextId: 1
EpsIndAmbrMaxUl: 320000000
EpsIndAmbrMaxDl: 1024000000
EpsRoamRestrict: TRUE
EpsTenantId: 1
EpsIndContextId: 1
EpsIndContextId: 5
EpsIndContextId: 15
```

I want to make unique the EpsIndContextId for each dn, adding a number to the end, getting as a result a file like this:

```
dn: EpsStaInfId=EpsStaInf,serv=EPS,mscId=0015f5e3d05d4d52b0cb85db69474db3,ou=multiSCs,dc=three
structuralObjectClass: EpsStaticInf
objectClass: EpsStaticInf
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20220303153032Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220303153032Z
EpsStaInfId: EpsStaInf
EpsProfileId: 10
EpsOdb: 0
EpsRoamAllow: TRUE
CDC: 1
EpsIndDefContextId: 1
EpsIndAmbrMaxUl: 320000000
EpsIndAmbrMaxDl: 1024000000
EpsRoamRestrict: TRUE
EpsTenantId: 1
EpsIndContextId1: 1
EpsIndContextId2: 2

dn: EpsStaInfId=EpsStaInf,serv=EPS,mscId=0040fb1140104f9fbc4be38be3db5965,ou=multiSCs,dc=three
structuralObjectClass: EpsStaticInf
objectClass: EpsStaticInf
entryDS: 1
nodeId: 21
createTimestamp: 20220301120221Z
modifyTimestamp: 20220301120221Z
EpsStaInfId: EpsStaInf
EpsProfileId: 10
EpsOdb: 0
EpsRoamAllow: TRUE
CDC: 1
EpsIndDefContextId: 1
EpsIndAmbrMaxUl: 320000000
EpsIndAmbrMaxDl: 1024000000
EpsRoamRestrict: TRUE
EpsTenantId: 1
EpsIndContextId1: 1
EpsIndContextId2: 5
EpsIndContextId3: 15
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `sed` solution:

`sed -E 's/(^EpsIndContextId)(:) (.*$)/\1\3\2 \3/' prueba.ldif`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for a solution with sed and this one works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe '$i = 0 if /^dn:/; s/^EpsIndContextId\K/++$i/e' < prueba.ldif
```

Or editing the file `i`n-place:

```
perl -i -pe '$i = 0 if /^dn:/; s/^EpsIndContextId\K/++$i/e' prueba.ldif
```

Above, we reset the counter whenever a line starting with `dn:` is encountered. You could change `if /^dn:/` to `if /^$/` to search for empty lines instead or `unless /\S/` to search for blank lines (lines made up of only whitespace characters), or as @glennjackman suggests, use the paragraph mode with `-00` where records, instead of being lines, are delimited by sequences of one or more empty lines (2 or more newline characters), and use the `m` flag in the substitution for `^` to match at the start of each line in the subject (paragraph) instead of only at the start of the subject and the `g` flag to substitute every occurrence in the record:

```
perl -00 -pe '$i = 0; s/^EpsIndContextId\K/++$i/emg' < prueba.ldif
```

Comment: Similar, but reads the file a "paragraph" at a time: `perl -00 -pe '$i = 0; s/^EpsIndContextId\K/++$i/meg'`

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks, I've incorporated that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. Not only for the solution, but for the explanation so I can actually understand how the solution works instead of just copying and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

`POSIX awk`:

```
awk '/^dn: /{c=0} /^EpsIndContextId/{sub(/^EpsIndContextId/, "&"++c)} 1' test
```

Reset the counter (`c`) ad the beginning of each section (`dn`), so each time it finds an `EpsIndContextId` it increment the counter and add it to this.

Or as , **@Ed Morton** suggests :

```
awk '/^dn: /{c=0} sub(/^EpsIndContextId/, "&"c+1){c++} 1' test
```

to avoid using the same regexp twice.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton edited the answers.

Comment: thanks @StéphaneChazelas, modified.